# Coefficient Matrix of $T:\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a vector $\vec{u}=\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\u_2\\u_3\end{pmatrix}$, such that $\left|\vec{u}\right| =1$. We define a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $\vec{x}\rightarrow\vec{x}\cdot\vec{u}$. Find the coefficient matrix of $T$ under the standard basis. Denote by $V$=ker$T$. Find the dimension of $V$.

Any thoughts? I know that dim$V$ is obviously 2, but I'm not sure what the coefficient matrix would look like.

EDIT:

There are two more parts of this problem so I figured I would put them up here too.

Note that for any $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R^{3}}$ there is a unique decomposition $\vec{x} = \vec{x}^{\perp} + \vec{x}^{\parallel}$ such that $\vec{x}^{\perp}$ is perpendicular to $V$, and $\vec{x}^{\parallel}$ is parallel to $V$. Define a linear transformation $T^{'}:\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{3}$ given by $\vec{x}\rightarrow\vec{x}^{\parallel}$. Find the coefficient matrix of $T^{'}$ using the standard coordinates.

For this I used the identity $\vec{e}^{\parallel}=\vec{e}-c\vec{u}=\vec{e}-\frac{\vec{e}\cdot\vec{u}}{\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u}}\vec{u}$ with the basis $(\vec{e_1},\vec{e_2}, \vec{e_3})$ and got the following matrix:

$A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 -u_1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1-u_2 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1-u_3\end{bmatrix} \\$

but I'm not one hundred percent about this. Any feedback would be much appreciated.

The last part of the problem states:

Consider two vectors $\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that $\vec{v_1}\perp\vec{v_2}$ and $|\vec{v_1}| =|\vec{v_2}| =1$. Take $\mathcal{B} = \{ \vec{u},\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2} \}$. Show that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R^{3}}$, and find the $\mathcal{B}$-coefficient matrix of $T^{'}$.

I'm totally lost with this one. Would it be sufficient to show that  $V^{'} = \begin{pmatrix} u_1 & v_{11} & v_{21}\\u_2 & v_{12} & v_{22}\\u_3 & v_{13} & v_{23} \end{pmatrix}$ has the same structure as $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, i.e. $T^{'}$ is invertible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $\vec x$ in components $\vec x = (x_1, x_2, x_3)^t$, a column vector. Then $T(\vec x) = x_1u_1 + x_2u_2 + x_3u_3$.

(Note that there should be no vector over arrows on the component values $u_i$.)

As $x_1u_1 + x_2u_2 + x_3u_3$ is a real number, we can also think of as a $1 \times 1$ matrix.

Since $\vec x$ is a $3 \times 1$ matrix, the matrix representing $T$ must be a $1 \times 3$ matrix. Can you write it down now?

Comment: I think I have it. If $T(e_i) = \vec{u_i}$, then The matrix representing $T$ is just the $1\times 3$ equivalent of the components of $\vec{u}$, i.e. $V = \begin{pmatrix} u_i & u_2 & u_3\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Looks right ....

Answer (score 2):

If you apply T to the standard basis you get:

T($e_i$)=$u_i$ so the desired matrix is precisely a vector with the same components as $\vec{u}^{\,}$

Hope it helps